# UITapGestureRecognizer waiting for second tap, buttons slow

Tags: uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer waiting for a doubletap to zoom out an scrollview back to the original level. However there is a situation that I add a couple of buttons on top of the scrollview. These buttons react very slow (sluggishly) because once I tap a button, the app waiting for the second tap. If this does not come, the button is pressed.

Anyone have an idea on how to get the buttons to respond quickly? Can I temporarily disable the GestureRecogniser while the buttons are up?

Cheers
Nick

Comment: I am also having same issue.... but i think its kind of universal problem... which can be minimized if we could reduce the wait time for second tap. But no idea on how to do that..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about filtering touches on the buttons like so:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
// Don't recognize taps in the buttons
return ((! [self.button1 pointInside:[touch locationInView:self.button1] withEvent:nil]) &&
        (! [self.button2 pointInside:[touch locationInView:self.button2] withEvent:nil]));
}
```

?

Comment: You can actually do this instead, which is cleaner since you don't have to hardcode every button into the gr delegate: `return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];`