# In iOS, How to disallow gesture recognition in the toolbar?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uigesturerecognizer

My view has a toolbar with two buttons of type `UIBarButtonItem`. I'm trying to implement a gesture recognizer such that when I tap anywhere in the view except in the toolbar, I call a selector. Tapping on a bar button item in the toolbar should call that button's action method.  The view conforms to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and implements the `shouldReceiveTouch` method as follows:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
                                                shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *) touch {
  // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the toolbar
  if ((touch.view == self.sideOneBarButton.customView) &&
      (gestureRecognizer == self.tapRecognizer)) {
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

The problem is, when I tap on the toolbar button, `touch.view` is of type `UTToolbarTextButton*` which is an undocumented class, so my if statement fails and the `shouldReceiveTouch` always returns YES and my button event never gets called.

Ideally, I'd like to say: if the touch is anywhere in the toolbar, then return no.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I just discovered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer which has the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add that link within a self written answer to your question and accept it as soon as possible to prevent questions without answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to ignore the gesture on anything that isn't your central view.

For instance I have:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

tap.delegate = self;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Add the gesture delegate to the class:

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController<..,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,..>
```

and now the delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view == self.view)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return  NO;
}
```

This has worked out for me when I couldn't use the UIToolbar because of the gesture

Also, as @LandedGently has mentioned, there is more information here:

[UIButton inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)

so people don't miss the link in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

About the delegate function, this is good for me.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```