# IBAction does not fire when I add viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, responder-chain

I have several IBActions  attached to UIButtons.  The IBActions work fine until I add the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"View Did Load");
    [self addGestureRecognizersToView:drawImage];
}
```

After I add that chunk of code the IBActions do not fire.  The UIButtons highlight when I touch them, but none of the IBAction code gets hit.

Here is my addGestureRecognizers code:

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizersToView:(UIImageView *)theView {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    //panGesture.delegate = drawImage;
    [theView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    [panGesture release];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleFingerTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleFingerTap];
    [doubleFingerTap release];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [singleFingerTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [singleFingerTap release];
}
```

If I comment out the singleFingerTap code it works.  I'm guessing I should not be using alloc since I have already alloced that once before in doubleFingerTap?

Any ideas on what I might be missing here?

Comment: what does `addGestureRecognizersToView:` do?

Comment: There is nothing in your code snippet that should interfere with your IBActions. Can you post addGestureRecognizersToView?

Comment: yeah, there is something with


    //[self addGestureRecognizersToView:drawImage];

When I comment that line, the buttons start working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You single finger tap is hindering with the normal behavior of the button. You will have to make sure the touches get through unhindered.

```
[singleFingerTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the UITapGestureRecognizer is [intercepting the taps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer) that would otherwise have been handled by the UIButtons.

You can use [`gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return (touch.view != self.button1 && 
            touch.view != self.button2);
}
```

Alternatively, you could [hack the responder chain](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74).