# UIButton on top of UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

As in the title, I have an `UIView` sublcass with `UITapGR` added to it.

In the subclass of this class I'm laying few `UIButton`s on top of the view. `UIButton` won't receive any touches. When i tried to see `[[tapGR view] class]` it was `UIButton`'s parent view. Calling `setCancelsTouchesInView` to NO won't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using single tap ...numberOfTapsRequired = 1 and using your button's frame etc. for each button that you want to use concurrently with other recognizers.

Comment: found it [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to ignore the touch event for the `UIButton`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to click through something you can

```
.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

Comment: yes, but i stil want to use UITapGestureRecognizer, if i make 

    .setUserInteractionEnabled = NO 

i'm not able to receive events from UITapGR

Comment: but the recognizer is set on the UIVIew? That's why you should disable the interaction on the button, or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: the case is that UIView have UITapGR on it, and on top of that UIView i've got UIButton, and i need to use both things