# UIPageViewController disable scrolling

Tags: ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController with transitionStyle `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` and navigationOrientation `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical`

I also have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the view and I want to disable page scrolling when the pan gesture is active.

I am trying to set the following when the gesture begins:

```
pageViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This seems to have no effect, or it appears to work sporadically.

The only other way I have found to do it (which works) is to set the UIPageViewController dataSource to nil while the pan gesture is running, however this causes a huge delay when resetting the dataSource.

Answer (score 22):

UIPageViewController uses some UIScrollView object to handle scrolling (at least for transitionStyle `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`). You can iterate by controller's subviews `pageViewController.view.subviews` to get it. Now, you can easly enable/disable scrolling:

```
- (void)setScrollEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forPageViewController:(UIPageViewController*)pageViewController
{
    for (UIView *view in pageViewController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:UIScrollView.class]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:enabled];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for a while and this is the best answer i've found for disabling swiping on UIPageViewController but keeping the tap movement.

Comment: In swift, if you like condensed stuff a bit hard to read:    `pageViewController.view.subviews.flatMap({ $0 as? UIScrollView}).forEach({$0.isScrollEnabled = enabled})`

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using swift instead of objective-c, here is Squikend's solution transposed.

```
func findScrollView(#enabled : Bool) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
      if view is UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = view as UIScrollView
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = enabled;
      } else {
        println("UIScrollView does not exist on this View")
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is complicating this very very much.

This is the whole function you need to disable or enable the scroll.

```swift
    func enableScroll(_ enable: Bool) {
        dataSource = enable ? self : nil
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4.2 Version of the answer

```
func findScrollView(enabled: Bool) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            let scrollView = view as! UIScrollView
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = enabled
        } else {
            print("UIScrollView does not exist on this View")
        }

    }
}
```

then yourpagecontorller.findScrollView(enabled: false)

Answer (score -2):

You may also disable gesture recognizers.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
{
    recognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Unlike the popular answer, which relies on existing of the inner `UIScrollView`, this one uses public `gestureRecognizers` array. The underlying scroll view may not exist if you use book-style paging.