# Disable/enable scrolling in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I got a `viewController` which inherits from `UIPageViewController` ( `@interface PageScrollViewController : UIPageViewController` ) Now I'm wondering how I can enable and disable the scrolling from the `UIPageViewController`? When using a `UIScrollView` you would do `setScrollEnabled:NO` and  `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` isn't an option since this blocks the whole `UIView` instead of just the scrolling.

**EDIT**
This is in the `PageScrollViewController : UIPageViewController` class:

```
if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"NotificationDisable"]){
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the disable notification!");
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try looping through the `gestureRecognizers` of the `UIPageViewController` and disable/enable them:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {        
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Note: as found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103613/uipageviewcontroller-returns-no-gesture-recognizers-in-ios-6), this method will only work for `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`. You may want to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293661/184245) (although it seems to be a bit hacky).

```
 for recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers {
    recognizer.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Where do you execute this loop? Would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: So you're getting the "Successfully received ..." message? If so, try `NSLog(@"Gesture recognizers: %@",self.gestureRecognizers)`

Comment: Yes I get the "Successfully received..." messsage. The NSLog shows me: Gesture recognizers: (
)

Comment: With the second solution you gave me, how can I disable and enable the scroll then if I've put the code in viewDidLoad?

Comment: It is already stated in this answer: `One workaround that comes to my mind is laying a transparent subview on top of your UIPageViewController and add to it a UIPanGestureRecognizer to intercept that kind of gesture and not forward further. You could enable this view/recognizer when disabling the gesture is required.`

Answer (score 12):

Or you can cast in your PagingVC To disable paging:

```
self.delegate = nil;
self.dataSource = nil;
```

And for enable it again:

```
self.delegate = self;
self.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 8):

I did the following thing (I have a controller that holds UIPageViewController).

```
self.pageController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

And when you want to enable swipe or scroll, just enable user interaction.

Comment: Unfortunately this also disables any controls you have in the vc.

Comment: As @Shinonuma said: "self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; isn't an option since this blocks the whole UIView instead of just the scrolling."

Comment: @MárioCarvalho yes, it disables any gesture, that is the flaw of this solution. :( I posted this, since it can help to someone and be enough (like for me) while searching its solution.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the UIPageViewController `dataSource` property to `nil` prevents scrolling, because the page view controller does not have a way to determine the "next" view controller to transition to.

```
self.dataSource = nil // scrolling disabled

self.dataSource = self // scrolling enabled
```

Comment: this is the best answer actually, in case your tab page is also a scrollview - this disables paging but gives you control over the vc still

Answer (score 3):

`UIPageViewController` manages a `UIScrollView` internally to get things done. We can find out that `UIScrollView` and update its `isScrollEnabled` property.

```swift
let view = myPageViewController.view
for subview in view.subviews {
    if let scrollview = subview as? UIScrollView {
        scrollview.isScrollEnabled = false
        break
    }
}
```

Or use this `UIPageViewController` extension.

```swift
extension UIPageViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let scrollview = subview as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollview
            }
        }
        fatalError()
    }
    
    var isScrollEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            return scrollView.isScrollEnabled
        }
        set {
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = newValue
        }
    }
}
```