# How to disable pageviewcontroller touches when the pageviewcontroller is of type UIPageViewControllerTypeScroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I am using pageviewcontroller in my application. My pageviewcontroller is of type scroll. My problem is how to disable the gesture recogniser when my pagviewcontroller is of type scroll.

This is possible in curl but not in scroll. My gesturerecognizer array is returning 0 when type is curl.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible

From `UIPageViewController.h`

```
// An array of UIGestureRecognizers pre-configured to handle user interaction. Initially attached to a view in the UIPageViewController's hierarchy, they can be placed on an arbitrary view to change the region in which the page view controller will respond to user gestures.
// Only populated if transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *gestureRecognizers;
```

Notice the **Only populated if transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.**

Here you have a workaround 
[UIPageViewController returns no Gesture Recognizers in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103613/uipageviewcontroller-returns-no-gesture-recognizers-in-ios-6)