# UISlider inside UIPageViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uislider, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController which is initialized like this:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                          navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

On one of the pages, there's a UISlider.

My problem is that when I have transitionstyle set to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`, it takes 150-200 ms before `beginTrackingWithTouch` is invoked on the slider.
This behavior is not seen when I use `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`, where the UISlider is selected instantly.

This means that unless the user waits a bit before dragging the slider (a video progress), the page will turn instead, which is far from ideal.

The Page curl animation does not meet the demands of the app, so any explanation or workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll gesture recognizers isn't available, you can use this:

```
for (UIView *view in pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I dont' understand how to use this solution ... Could you develop a bit more where to add this code, and why setting delaysContentTouches on the scrollView works ? Thanks

Comment: You can put this code in next line after creating your UIPageViewController. Or you can subclass UIPageViewController and put this code in viewDidLoad method, just use 'self' instead of 'pageViewController'. When 'delaysContentToushes' is 'NO', scroll view forwards touches to content immediately and didn't tries to perfrom scroll before content handles touches

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is a bit better for me, but the pageViewController still reacts first to a touch on the slider.

Comment: I don't get it either. I have no scroll view in my page subviews. just a slider

Comment: swift3:

`for view in view.subviews {
          if view is UIScrollView {
            (view as! UIScrollView).delaysContentTouches = false
          }
        }`

Comment: swift 4:  `for view in pageVC.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by add a pan gesture on UISlider and set:

```
self.sliderGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;  // make touch always triggered
```

and implement delegate method like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return otherGestureRecognizer.view.superview == self.parentViewController.view;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    // only receive touch in slider
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.slider.frame, touchLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the delegate of the page view controller gestures to the root view controller:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}
```

And then prevent the touch of the gestures if it appears inside UISlider which is a subclass of UIControl:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]] == NO); 
}
```

Comment: Problem is gesturerecognizers isn't set when transitionstyle= UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll, hence this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103613/uipageviewcontroller-returns-no-gesture-recognizers-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to add pan-gesture-recognizer to UIView which holds UISlider, so in the end I have
UIPageViewController->UIScrollView->...->MyView->UISlider
The 'MyView' thing had pan gesture registered to it which did nothing, but served just to NOT propagate events to scroll view.