# Using UISlider inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller, uislider

I'm working in XCode 8 / Swift 3. I'm having a UIPageViewController with three pages attached to it, and on the third page there's a UISlider. When you want to slide the element, the touch triggers the PageViewController and moves the page rather than the slider. You need to touch it for a second or so to be able to move it.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185042/uislider-inside-uipageviewcontroller) but this solution is 3 years old and I'm not able to convert it into current syntax. I couldn't find any current examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift translation of the accepted `Objective-C` from that other question

```
for view in pageViewController.view.subviews {
   if view is UIScrollView {
      (view as? UIScrollView)?.delaysContentTouches = false
   }
}
```