# How to disable user swiping in page view but still enable interaction with the subviews in the page view. e.x. button

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to disable users being able to swipe through page view controllers in swift but every method I try it also disable's any interaction with the subviews in the page view controller such as a button and being able to interact with a table view controller.

How would I approach this project.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13293661/312594

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.enabled = false
```