# How to block tap gesture on UIPageViewController with Scroll TransitionStyle

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to block the tap gesture (perfectly just the left border one, but both will be also fine, I will just add button for it) which is responded for changing pages in `UIPageViewController`.

I already tried this solution in 'viewDidLoad' method:

```
for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
    if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
        recognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

But it worked only for the case when `TransitionStyle` is set for `Page Curl`, in my case I need to use `Scroll TransitionStyle`.

Ps. I also found a comment in `UIPageViewController` implementation that `gestureRecognizers` are populated only if transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` so there will be needed some bigger "hack", hope you can help me with it.

Pps. Yes I found this - [UIPageViewController returns no Gesture Recognizers in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103613/uipageviewcontroller-returns-no-gesture-recognizers-in-ios-6) . solution but it's pretty old and in objC and I would be glad to use Swift here.

Ppps. Setting `dataSource` on `nil` won't work - I need swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UIGestureDelegate  and then to declane gesture when such are detected.

I think  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152294/1856499) you can see good example how to do it

Comment: It's the same problem as I wrote - it's working only for UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl and not working for Scroll TransitionStyle.