# Can we uses button inside a UIPageViewController in scroll mode in IOS6?

Tags: ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I tried this solution:

[UIButton interaction inside UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037448/uibutton-interaction-inside-uipageviewcontroller)

It says I should set delegate UIPageViewController gesture recoqnizer. But it returns zero.

For example, if I subclass of UIPageViewController and in viewDidload I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PO(self.gestureRecognizers);
    PO(self.view.gestureRecognizers);

}
```

I got:

```
self.gestureRecognizers: (
)
self.view.gestureRecognizers: (null)
```

Hence, I cannot set delegate for the UIPageViewController's gesture recoqnizers because I can't have a pointer to it. But that UIPageViewController absorb all taps that my button doesn't get pressed. So what should I do?

I tried many solutions from various similar questions in stack overflow. It all fails.

This is a simple problem. I have a UIButton inside a UIPageViewController. Why it has be to be this difficult?

What is the delegate of UIPageViewController's gesture recoqnizers anyway?

Also UIPageViewController doesn't have rootViewController and I am very confused why people say it has.

Answer (score 0):

Show us, how do you subclass UIPageViewController.

This works at least:

```
  UIPageViewController *pageVC = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"%@", pageVC.gestureRecognizers);
```

This controller has gestureRecognizers property for sure:

[image]

Comment: Is your UIPageViewController in scroll mode rather than page curl mode?

Comment: This is my sample code, I just tried to check what you tell. I didn't change default mode. I guess, it should work in both modes for a root class (not subclasses) according to the documentation - no notes on that.

Comment: Yes, by default the transition style is page curl. So, you are right. When I tried to init it with a transition style scroll, it didn't have recognizers. So, the problem is not in subclassing. Looks like in that mode it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, how do I turn off the tap gestureRecoqnizers if I cannot access the gestureRecoqnizers? I want buttons inside the UIPageViewController to work.