# Use two-fingered gesture in a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a table view so that I can scroll down a list with one finger, but also have a two-fingered gesture to go to another view without scrolling. I have tried adding custom gesture recognisers to the table view, but can't seem to get it to work; it ignores the gestures. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [UIButton inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer) You might want to check if a similar situation is present in your case too. Also, you might wanna make sure you add the gesture recognizers to the tableview and not the tableviewcell's `contentview`.