# UIButton not calling action in iOS 5 but works in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uibutton, uicontrol

I have a `UIButton` that is loaded from a xib file as an `IBOutlet` property of a view controller. I attach a selector to the button in the `viewDidLoad` of my view controller:

```
[_myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In iOS 6 everything works, but when i run on the simulator in iOS 5.0 the selector doesn't get called. The button does highlight when it is touched.

Another thing to note is that the button is in a `UIView` that has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to it. The `UITapGestureRecognizer` for this view gets called in iOS 5.0 when the button is tapped, (it does not get called in iOS 6, where the button's selector is called instead).

I don't have a device running iOS 5 so I haven't tested on a device, just the simulator.

Does anyone know what is happening here, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have explained very beautifully the cause of the problem. On iOS 5, a UITapGestureRecognizer on a button's superview interferes with the action of the button. On iOS 6, they fixed this: they introduced a UIView event `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, and a button automatically returns NO for a tap gesture recognizer attached to a superview.

For iOS 5, you'll need to use a delegate method on the tap gesture recognizer to stop it from recognizing if the tapped view was the button.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try that solution out.

Comment: This answer included the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515539/uibutton-not-works-in-ios-5-x-everything-is-fine-in-ios-6-x

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was also using a general `UITapGestureRecognizer` for dismissing the keyboard opened by a text field when the user would tap anywhere on the main view.

I fixed this by only adding a gesture recognizer when the keyboard shows up (see

`- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n` or

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(VDTextFieldWithError *)textField`)

and then removing the gesture recognizer when hiding the keyboard (thus removing the selector in the selector method of the recognizer itself)