# button not getting pressed in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I've been trying for a while to find the best way to word this problem and hopefully have come up with something decent.

I have an app with one main screen with a few buttons on it that segue to popovers.  I have a Tap Gesture Recognizer for the screen as well.

On an iOS5 iPad if I tap the buttons, the Tap Gesture Recognizer seems to be handling the action but on an iOS6 iPad, the buttons handle the action.  The only way to get the button to press, instead of the Tap Gesture Recognizer, is to do a long press.

Why do the taps "pass through" the Tap Gesture Recognizer in iOS6 but get caught by it in iOS5?

I'd be happy to add any code but this is pretty much all storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
    return NO;
}
return YES;}
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A google searched turned up the answer on this site:

[UIButton inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)

as well as

[UIButton not works in iOS 5.x , everything is fine in iOS 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515539/uibutton-not-works-in-ios-5-x-everything-is-fine-in-ios-6-x)

Comment: Yes.  The answer above that I selected is exactly the same as the answer in the links above.