# Superview's tabgesture getting called on subview(button) click

Tags: uibutton, click, subview

My head is getting stuck here.

I am having One **UIView added tap gesture** to that view(no of tap=1) On this gesture im calling method - callTap()

Added UIButton as subview to that uiview. this button is having one selector method - callClick()

As I am **tapping on button callTap() is getting called instead of callClick()**

I want to know reason behind this behavior. 
And hot to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to this question which is answered well.

[UIButton inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)