# Using a UITapGestureRecognizer to make keyboard hides, it doesn't work when I touch inside a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have declared in my header file this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap;
```

And on `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    tap.enabled = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

I've added `UITextFieldDelegate`, and added this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    tap.enabled = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

If I touches anywhere outside the keyboard, it disappears, but if I touch in a `UIButton` it doesn't disappear.

**Do you know why?**

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer)

Answer (score 0):

The UIButton intercepts and handles the touch (not propagating it). One option would be to set your view controller as the gesture recognizer delegate and implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

But in your case i think it would be enough to dismiss the keyboard in the method that fires when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {


    if (touch.view == self.button) {//change it to your condition UIButton
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a target-action pairing for when the user touches down on the button:

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```