# SubView not Considered a part of MainView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have many SubViews in my `UIView`, and many of them have `UIButtons` in them. One of the subviews- `_bottomView` (Coordinates- **(0,519,320,49)**) has an error. It does not recognise the click events on the buttons placed inside it.

I tried placing a `UIButton` covering the entire `_bottomView` and the click event from that Button (`testButton`) is not being recognised either.

I tried adding a tapRecogniser to the code and the tap from every point, EXCEPT the points within the _bottomView are recognised. TapRecogniser Code below

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    _bottomView.userInteractionEnabled=true;


-(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"got a tap in the region i care about");
}
```

I tried  `[self.view addSubview:_bottomView];` and that didn't help either. What could be the issue?

[image: ViewController]

[image: Screen]

Comment: Do you want the button to handle the tap or the UITapGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: I want the button to handle the tap. But I figured, that the View inside which the button exists must atleast handle the tapGesturerecognizer, right?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344341/uibutton-inside-a-view-that-has-a-uitapgesturerecognizer).

Read this document(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW3) for clarification.

Comment: The button should handle it's own taps unless you need both the button and the view handle separate taps as @RahulWakade pointed out.

Comment: @RahulWakade no that article doesn't help. The questioner has UITapGestureRecognizer working, in his case. I don't NEED tapRecognizer in my app. I just put that in to check if Tap is being detected in that particular view.

Comment: Can you set clipSubview to yes to your `_bottomView` and check that?

Comment: @Yan Button is NOT recognising its own taps, thats why I put in a recogniser, which proved that the view in which the button resides, itself is not detecting taps

Comment: Are you creating buttons programmatically or in the storyboards? If programmatically post that code if you can

Comment: @Yan in the storyboard.

Comment: @Vijay how do I clip subview? what is the code?

Comment: Just want to make sure if you setting up the action function and is it connected to the button?

Comment: yes, I have them all set up

Comment: @SidharthJDev, Check this on your _bottomView in XIB or storyboard. http://i.stack.imgur.com/w2V0T.png

Comment: @Vijay tried that too. No change

Comment: @SidharthJDev Can you show your screen?

Comment: Added the screens.. Circled out the buttons, that don't recognise the tap. The red view in Simulator screen is the view in question. Is everything understandable?

Comment: @Vijay can you understand everything from the screens i posted?

Comment: @SidharthJDev Yes.  Can you check debug view hierarchy in xcode that is there any view overrides on bottomview?

Comment: @SidharthJDev, Move your button to top in your view. He XIB hierarchy should be like this Button, ImageView, Label.. And remove your gesture and try..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94284/discussion-between-sidharth-j-dev-and-vijay).

Answer (score 0):

If your view is not receiving touches

1. Make sure that your `UIView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`
2. Make sure that the view is within the bounds of its superview, and the superview is within the bounds of window.You can print the frames of views using `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame));`

Comment: If you read the code and see the screens that I posted, you will see that I have both of them checked

Comment: what are the frames of `bottomView`, its superview, and also the `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`  ?

Comment: superview-{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
bottomView-{{0, 519}, {320, 49}}

Comment: po mainScreen
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 568))
 (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 568))

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped. I had to delete the entire View Controller and redo the whole thing. That obviously solved the problem.